# How to loop over table rows to export values in a CSV

Tags: javascript, loops, html-table

I have this table here and would like to save its content in a CSV. At the moment I am as far as this only works for the first row of the table. But I can add more rows via a button and now I want the saving to CSV to work for all rows.

I can't handle looping over the table, can anyone show me how?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jg3Lpt74/31/

```js
function csv() {
    
            var titel = document.getElementById('titel').value;
            var vorname = document.getElementById('vorname').value;
            var nachname = document.getElementById('nachname').value;
            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    
            const rows = [[titel, vorname, nachname, email]];
            let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
            rows.forEach(function (rowArray) {
                let row = rowArray.join(";");
                csvContent += row + "\r\n";
            });
    
            var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
            link.setAttribute("download", "export.csv");
            document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
    
            link.click(); // This will download the data file named "my_data.csv".
    
        }
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border=1>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Geschlecht</th>
        <th>Anrede</th>
        <th>Titel</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Nachname</th>
        <th>E-Mail</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk"/>
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-field">
                <div>
                    <select class="browser-default genderSelect" required>
                        <option value="new" selected>Bitte auswählen</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-field">
                <div>
                    <select class="browser-default gsAddress" required>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="titel" id="titel" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="vorname" id="vorname" type="text" class="validate">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="nachname" id="nachname" type="text" class="validate">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="validate">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is not working: I can't fill out the form.

Comment: Yes i just saw that, but the export button works and it gets the values of the input fields. So basically everything whats needed, works.

Comment: I edited your fiddle to work

Comment: @HerrSerker Thank you

Comment: I will edit it some more

Comment: @Adrian, now your snippet works. The CSV is faulty still

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

The input elements within your initial table row have `id` tags. You're adding a new row by appending a clone the last row of the table.

```
var newRow = $("#myTable tr:last").clone().appendTo("#myTable");
```

This means that all new inputs will have the same `id`s. If you attempt to access the input values via the input `id`s then you will only get the first one present in the DOM.

Furthermore, in your `csv` function you are only getting the inputs once. You need to get them every time you access a row.

### Solution

Change the table in your HTML to have inputs of the form:

```
<input name="titel" class="titel" type="text">
```

Note that the `id` attribute has been changed to a `class`. The full `tbody`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk"/>
                <span></span>
                </label>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-field">
                <div>
                <select class="browser-default genderSelect" required>
                    <option value="new" selected>Bitte auswählen</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-field">
                <div>
                <select class="browser-default gsAddress" required>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="titel" class="titel" type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="vorname" class="vorname" type="text" class="validate">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="nachname" class="nachname" type="text" class="validate">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="email" class="email" type="text" class="validate">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In your `csv` function get a NodeList of your table rows. You then step through the list, i.e. accessing the table row by row, and get the inputs from each row by their class name. From this you can build your csv file.

```
function csv() {
    var rowList = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

    for( var r = 0; r < rowList.length; r++  ) {
        var row = rowList[ r ];
        var titel = row.getElementsByClassName('titel')[0].value;
        var vorname = row.getElementsByClassName('vorname')[0].value;
        var nachname = row.getElementsByClassName('nachname')[0].value;
        var email = row.getElementsByClassName('email')[0].value;
        csvContent += [titel, vorname, nachname, email].join(";") + "\r\n";
    }

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "export.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

    link.click(); // This will download the data file named "my_data.csv".
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With more rows you can no longer use the same ids in each row of the table.

If you add `titel`, `vorname` etc. as class names rather than ids, then you will be able to call `document.getElementsByClassName('titel');` to get the whole `titel` column as a collection of entries and then iterate over this collection

Comment: If i call the class name, the value is empty. I get nothing back.